# react-native-pdf giving error of Unable to resolve module react-native-blob-util

Tags: react-native-pdf

```
import React, { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import { RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { FundStackParamsList } from "../../navigation/Params";
import { useTheme } from '../../theme';
import { EdgeInsets, useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { Endpoints, getTokens } from "../../api";
import PDFView from 'react-native-pdf';

interface ReportViewScreenProps {
  navigation: StackNavigationProp<FundStackParamsList, 'HistoricReportsView'>;
  route: RouteProp<FundStackParamsList, 'HistoricReportsView'>;
}

const HistoricReportViewScreen: FunctionComponent<ReportViewScreenProps> = (props) => {
  const theme = useTheme(),
    edgeInsets = useSafeAreaInsets(),
    style = styles(theme, edgeInsets);

  const [pdfData, setPdfData] = useState<string | null>(null); // State to store Base64 encoded PDF data


  useEffect(() => {
    getTokens()
      .then((token) => {
        fetch(Endpoints.FUND_REPORT_FILE(props.route.params.refID), {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access}`,
          },
        })
          .then((response) => response.blob())
          .then((blob) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = () => {
              const base64Data = reader.result as string;
              setPdfData(`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64Data}`);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching PDF:', error);
          });
      });
  }, [props.route.params.refID]);
  

  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
    {pdfData ? (
      <PDFView
        source={{ uri: pdfData, cache: true }}
        onLoadComplete={() => console.log('PDF loaded')}
        onError={(error) => console.error('Error loading PDF:', error)}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
      />
      ) : 
      (
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={theme.colors.primary} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = (theme: ReturnType<typeof useTheme>, edgeInsets: EdgeInsets) => StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.colors.background,
  },
  // ...other styles
});

export default HistoricReportViewScreen;
```

This is my code in react native i'm getting a blog pdf file from backend and i want to show it in my app but when i installed react-native-pdf it's giving me error of Unable to resolve module react-native-blob-util.
I'm using  "react-native": "0.70.8", and    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",

I installed react-native-blob-util but after that i get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConstants' of null, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
        A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
```

A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

I'm using expo go for development.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in app.json

```
"plugins": [
  "@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util",
  "@config-plugins/react-native-pdf"
]
```

Install following packages in devDependencies :

```
"@config-plugins/react-native-blob-util": "^0.0.0",
"@config-plugins/react-native-pdf": "^0.0.0"
```

Install following package : "react-native-blob-util"

Refer link : https://github.com/expo/examples/tree/master/with-pdf